# Button not coming in the same line as the textarea

Tags: html, css

As shown below, the button is not aligned next to the textarea :

[image]

The following is the html code :

```
<div>
      <form>

          <textarea  name="comment" id="new-post" rows="2" cols="45" placeholder="Add a comment"> 
          </textarea>


         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" style="display: inline-block;" 
          align="right">Add comment</button>
     </form>

</div>
```

Comment: vertical-align:top to both element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to force them as inline elements.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <form>

          <textarea  name="comment" id="new-post" rows="2" cols="45" placeholder="Add a comment"> 
          </textarea>


         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" style="display: inline-block;" 
          align="right">Add comment</button>
     </form>

</div>
```